# Errno 13 Permission denied.... I can't access this JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to open a JSON file.

Here is my code:

```
import json

fh = open('C:/Users/Joker/Desktop/Python/Code3/roster')

data = json.loads(fh)

for i in data:
    print(i)
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joker\Desktop\Python\jsondatabase.py", line 3, in <module>
    fh = open('C:/Users/Joker/Desktop/Python/Code3/roster')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Joker/Desktop/Python/Code3/roster'
[Finished in 0.135s]
```

How can I access the data?

Edit: It worked when I ran as admin. Thanks everyone!

Comment: do you have the file open somewhere?

Comment: have you tried running your script from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: also the file path looks incomplete, mostly because it's missing a `'.json'` at the end

Comment: Do you try to execute it as superuser?

Comment: This is a filesystem-level issue, not a Python issue. If `open()` in Python gives a permission-denied error, so will a `type` command (Windows equivalent to `cat`) or anything else.

Comment: I did have it running elsewhere. I closed the program, and I changed the code so that it says roster.json. I'm still getting the same error though....

Comment: The permission issue is likely with one of the sub-directories in the path you're trying to access. Also note that you should use the `json.load` method instead of `json.loads` if you're going to pass to it a file object.

Comment: BTW, the potential issue here where you can't open a file if another program has it open is very much a Windows-ism. Consider switching to a *real* OS.

Comment: What are some other issues with Windows?

Comment: SO comments on an unrelated question aren't the place to gripe about windows folks *cries in docker for windows edition*

Answer (score 1):

The code as written orphans the file handler, leaving it open. It may very well be open in another program which is hard to see from the process manager, but you should edit to:

```
import json

with open('C:/Users/Joker/Desktop/Python/Code3/roster.json', "r") as fh:

    data = json.load(fh)

    for i in data:
        print(i)
```

To clear the orphaned handler you could try wack-a-mole with the task manager or just restart your machine.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue since the OP states in the comment that changing the file name by adding `.json` to it doesn't make a difference in the error. It's more likely that he has a real permission issue with accessing one of the sub-directories in the path leading to the file.

Comment: He should be able to check by trying to navigate there, but he hasn't posted about that yet

Comment: @blhsing because the code as written orphans the file handler, this will be the issue soon enough if it isn't in the first place. So even if my answer doesn't address the core problem it's part of the solution I think.

Comment: @CharlesLandau An orphaned file handler would only cause a permission error if the file was opened in write mode, which isn't the case here.